# Ubuntu GUI SMB share with password inaccessible from Windows 7

Tags: nautilus, samba, shared-folders, smb

I want to share my private files on Ubuntu 20.04 via SMB with Windows 7 machine. The share must be protected with password.

In Ubuntu, in Files app, I click with right button on a folder, choose "Local Network Share" and check "Share this folder".

Windows machine sees the shared folder. I do double click, enter my username and password, and hit Enter. But it says "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password".

I tried different domain names: `WORKGROUP`, `Unix User`, hostname of the Ubuntu machine, empty domain. No success.

I tried creating a user and setting a password in the Samba DB with `smbpasswd`. No success.

All manuals I could find in the Internet shows how to create a guest share, which is not what I need.

I can see the share in `net usershare`:

```
gsovetov@gsovetov-mate:~$ sudo net usershare info --long 
[develop]
path=/home/gsovetov/develop
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:R,Unix User\gsovetov:F,
guest_ok=n
```

I can connect it from the same machine:

```
gsovetov@gsovetov-mate:~$ smbclient '\\192.168.1.252\develop' -U gsovetov%SecurePassword
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \> ls 
  .                                   D        0  Sat Jun 20 12:50:34 2020
  ..                                  D        0  Thu Jul 16 19:28:08 2020
  qweqweqwe                           D        0  Thu Apr 23 20:34:23 2020
  asdasdasdasd                        D        0  Thu Apr 23 19:24:28 2020
```

Please, help me to access the share from Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

The problem was that the Windows 7 machine attempted to authenticate with NTLMv1 while it was disabled on Ubuntu 20.04 in favor of NTLMv2.

The fix is to force NTLMv2 for client connection on the Windows machine: set `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa!LmCompatibilityLevel` to `5` or `3`: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc960646(v=technet.10).

Another but less secure fix is to enable NTLMv1 in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` with `ntlm auth = yes`. Note that NTLMv2 has additional protection against replay attacks: https://miriamxyra.com/2017/11/08/stop-using-lan-manager-and-ntlmv1/.

## How I found it

1. Set log level in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` with `log level = 5`. Although, `log level = 2` would've been enough.
2. Compared logs of a failed connection from Windows 7 and a succeeded connection from Ubuntu 20.04 itself:

From Windows:

```
[2020/07/17 12:11:17.453906,  2] ../../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:429(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: NTLMv1 passwords NOT PERMITTED for user gsovetov
[2020/07/17 12:11:17.454843,  2] ../../source3/auth/auth.c:343(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [gsovetov] -> [gsovetov] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD, authoritative=1
[2020/07/17 12:11:17.454887,  2] ../../auth/auth_log.c:635(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [SMB2,(null)] user [WORKGROUP]\[gsovetov] at [Fri, 17 Jul 2020 12:11:17.454866 MSK] with [NTLMv1] status [NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD] workstation [RHN] remote host [ipv4:192.168.1.72:49609] mapped to [WORKGROUP]\[gsovetov]. local host [ipv4:192.168.1.252:445]
```

From Ubuntu:

```
[2020/07/17 12:09:36.639590,  3] ../../auth/auth_log.c:635(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [SMB2,(null)] user [WORKGROUP]\[gsovetov] at [Fri, 17 Jul 2020 12:09:36.639576 MSK] with [NTLMv2] status [NT_STATUS_OK] workstation [GSOVETOV-MATE] remote host [ipv4:192.168.1.252:55250] became [GSOVETOV-MATE]\[gsovetov] [S-1-5-21-1148495091-2039333689-3294533319-1001]. local host [ipv4:192.168.1.252:445] 
  {"timestamp": "2020-07-17T12:09:36.639644+0300", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 2}, "eventId": 4624, "logonId": "0", "logonType": 3, "status": "NT_STATUS_OK", "localAddress": "ipv4:192.168.1.252:445", "remoteAddress": "ipv4:192.168.1.252:55250", "serviceDescription": "SMB2", "authDescription": null, "clientDomain": "WORKGROUP", "clientAccount": "gsovetov", "workstation": "GSOVETOV-MATE", "becameAccount": "gsovetov", "becameDomain": "GSOVETOV-MATE", "becameSid": "S-1-5-21-1148495091-2039333689-3294533319-1001", "mappedAccount": "gsovetov", "mappedDomain": "WORKGROUP", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": null, "passwordType": "NTLMv2", "duration": 7842}}
```

3. Found how to enable NTLMv1 for incoming connections in Samba: https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2018/08/31/ubuntu-18-samba-and-ntlmv1/.
4. Found how to enable NTLMv2 for client connection on Windows: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc960646(v=technet.10). A recommended value is `5`: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4090105/how-to-audit-domain-controller-use-of-ntlmv1-and-ntlmv2. (I'm not sure what's the default value. It might be me who changed this setting a few years ago and forget about it.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble connecting to the Ubuntu machine, it is possible to setup an SMB share on the Windows machine and transfer files that way.

I have done this before to transfer files between my old PC and my newish one.
A guide on how to do this can be found [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewZvTh2oEso)